# Good practice in implementing multi sprite (as skins) in 2d unity game

Tags: sprites, unity, character

so, I want to make such functionality in my 2d game with unity :

> Multi skin character, with similar control and functionality, and with
>   possible different gimmicks (such as crossy road's characters, which
>   some modify game environment and / or have unique death animation, yet THEY
>   CAN ONLY JUMP AROUND a.k.a only cosmetic).

Here's so far what I did :

> Make each character into separate gameobjects and prefabs, and then if
>   I need to find a particular script in current active char, I use
>   `Gameobject.Find()`. The problem is, if I need to apply a script, I need to > manually attach it 1 by 1 to each char gameobjects, which I find will  create problems if the character number grows.

Is that a good practice? Or there's any more good / best practice on this problem?

P.S.

1. I once read `Gameobject.Find()` is slow, so if possible, I want to avoid that.
2. I use bone-based sprite animation, so, I think, changing just the `Sprite` in `SpriteRenderer` component won't work.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically you just change the sprites through code depending upon the skin type.
You should not put the code in Late Update as shown in the tutorial as its just for demonstration purpose. Call the function only once when you want to update the skin.

You can find the complete tutorial in this link -
https://youtu.be/HM17mAmLd7k?t=1609

And the entire source code for the tutorial in this link - http://goo.gl/6oSzDx

Comment: Hmm. I need to clarify something, how if I want to make "walk" animation? Is it by make "walk" animation on such controller, and then "pointing" each skin animation to that "walk" animation? If the answer is yes, then I think I got your point.

Comment: are you using sprite animation or unity animation with cut out parts??

Comment: Bone based / cut out part (as ive stated earlier in op)

Comment: ohh , wait ill update my answer

Comment: Ah nice! Btw i need to try it first so, since I am now on trip, maybe i'll accept it next week after i come back. Thanks so much

Comment: :( :( :( .......  Lol just kidding

Comment: Downvoters care to explain why?